# ajax call to the same page: setcookie creates cookie in the browser but $_COOKIE is not set

Tags: php, setcookie

I have a single php file with an ajax call to itself. At the beginning of the file there is the php script:

```php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
    stuff...
    setcookie("my-cookie-name",$uuid,time()+2592000);
    //even with this it's not working:
    //$_COOKIE["my-cookie-name"]=$uuid;
    stuff...
    die();
}
```

The cookie is set in the browser but in another php file (in the same directory) isset($_COOKIE["my-cookie-name"]) returns false.

I tried a simple two script example to test cookies and they work as they should. Coul that die() be the cause? Why?

Link to the full code: https://paste.ee/p/2vf9c

Comment: under cookies section does it show the cookie with the value

Comment: In chrome -> settings -> All cookies and site data, it does show the cookie.

Comment: ok then no issue with setting cookies . Please show us the code that you use to retrive the value

Comment: if(isset($_COOKIE["my-cookie-name"])) {...} else echo "not set"; I get "not set". I will link the full code if interested.

Comment: yes please add the full code that used to retrive

Comment: Can you echo `$uuid`? does it have a value?

Comment: as you can see from the full code I just posted, $uuid is also stored into the database, and the row is added with the same content as the cookie in the browser.

Comment: give us a snap of browser cookies too

Comment: please check with this and just tell what does it output `<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
`

Comment: Cookie named 'my-cookie-name' is not set!

Answer (score 1):

The die() doesn't affect the cookie. Well[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_http_setcookie) I figured out that you have to reload the page before the cookie will take effect. Have a look

Also, I tried your code. I just remove the post since I don't want another html forms to do this. Here check this out.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $uuid = "<b>Hello here is your variable</b>";
    setcookie("my-cookie-name",$uuid,time()+2592000);
    if(isset($_COOKIE["my-cookie-name"])){
        echo "Cookie is now set: ".$_COOKIE["my-cookie-name"];
    }else{
        header( "Location: ./" );
    }
    die();
?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the "Wellenter link description here" that should be a link. https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_http_setcookie

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand your answer. If you please could post/link the full content that entra.php should have, so that I can check how it works.

Comment: I made the following changes, but the result is the same:
https://www.diffchecker.com/tXJAd4Ct

Answer (score 0):

To the users who tried to help me, I sincerely apologize for hiding you the vital information to solve this problem. In the original code, the cookie name was different and contained the site name which I wanted to keep hidden.

I just found out that **dots in cookies name become underscore in $_COOKIE**.